# How to install docker on newst Raspbian (20-06-2019)?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I get the following results while following instruction on my **Raspberry3B** with **2019-06-20-raspbian-buster** installed:

The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/**raspbian 10 Release' does not have a Release file.**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
# Executing docker install script, commit: 2f4ae48
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian 10 Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Any hints?

Comment: there is a different guido for raspberry devices

Comment: try this guide https://maker-tutorials.com/docker-raspberry-pi-installieren-raspbian-debian-stretch-jessie/

Comment: Same stuff:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && sh get-docker.sh
# Executing docker install script, commit: 2f4ae48
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian 10 Release' does not have a Release file.